# Change font size and line distance/height in exported PDF from Jupyter Lab

Tags: r, pdf, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

I exported an R document from Jupyter Lab into a PDF. However, the line height between the document title, the author's name and the date is too small. Also, I would like to change the font size of the document title (I am *not* referring to the size of the headers in the document, I am aware these can be modified with '#'). I am guessing the line height was initially reduced since I manually added the author's name between the title and the date through editing the metadata. I am further guessing this problem could be possibly resolved by accessing the metadata of the document, but again, this is where I am stuck. I am not using R Markdown on purpose here because I prefer the way the markdown from Jupyter displays the code (it looks nicer and more professional imho).

Hope the question is clear - let me know if you need more information.
Thank you in advance!